How to Integrate FreeRTOS on the i.MX6UL-Var-DART Board(yocto project)
I am working on i.MX6UL-Var-DART board with a Yocto build (Kirkstone). My goal is to reduce unnecessary tasks in the Yocto build and focus on enabling video features. Here i plan to use FreeRTOS. Is it feasible to configure Yocto this way, how can I integrate FreeRTOS into this yocto build.

FreeRTOS is made to work on MCUs, I think the iMX6 is not supported. Maybe you can take a look at poky-tiny.
